# Ready made PHP modules

Tags: php, module, frameworks

Are there any frame work / modules that I can use when building web apps from scratch (php, sql)?
I am sure that coders don't write login, signup, etc. features (of typical web 2.0 apps) from scratch, they got modules that they refer to / reuse.

Is there a possibility to gain access to those modules to use?

Thanks

Comment: Do you know anything about composer??

Comment: I suggest you do a simple google search for "php framework".

Comment: I was looking for frameworks like laravel but those didn't seem to fit what I am looking for (or I didn't inderstand the concept).
William, I actually dont know anything about composer. I am googling it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exaggerating but there might be a **thousand** PHP frameworks. All you have to do is to google **PHP Frameworks** .

Some well known ones are :

1. [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)
2. [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
3. [CodeIgnitor](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)
4. [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/)
5. [Symfony](http://symfony.com/)
6. [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/)

... and the list goes on and on

Comment: Thanks. I don't even know if the thing I am looking for is called "framework" ( I am german so I dont know the proper expression).
I am looking for some sort of library, that has different ready made scripts in it like login, forget passowrd, private messaging, etc. and I can pick one and add it to my project and work on the appearance of the site

Answer (score 0):

you can use laravel if you have basic concept about php and mvc framework you will be able to control over laravel very well, when you create module it will gives you crud methods by default you just have to get an idea about its namingConvention and use. please visit https://scotch.io/tutorials/simple-laravel-crud-with-resource-controllers